# Which API Objects support Quotas , Kubernetes kubectl

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, google-kubernetes-engine

Looking for a `kubectl` command to get the list of all the objects on which quotas can be applied , or a complete list somewhere else. In the documentation I could not find a complete list. OR does it mean all of them support quota?

**Use case:**

We need to apply quota on all the namespace resouces. But I doubt all of them support quota ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of objects that is supported by kubernetes till now . They are categorized in Compute Resource Quota,Storage Resource Quota,Object Count Quota. Below is the kubernetes doc link.

[supported api objects for quotas](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/)

Comment: Thanks , i was lookig for object count quotas which one are supporting , the rest of them , i had already done